# Getting a function to execute on a node server when data recieved

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'll try to keep this simple. I'm working on a paging app.

**What I have**: A terminal without internet, running a desktop app made from node.js using express,ejs, ect. I also have a physical server with internet access and a mssql database on this machine I have a node.js server that interfaces with the database, collects the data and send sends it over to terminal via websocket when the app is launched, the node.js app gets this data and is rendered to the web interface using ejs. This data is displayed in a form with a button that when clicked fires the app.post route. In the app.post that data is packaged in an array, and sent back to the server using a second websocket connection. I can then take that form data (a name, phone#, and a radio button value) and form a SMS message using and using twilio send a message to that number (with addition info)

Yes, I have two websocket connections one Server > client serves data to web app
and another client > server serves form data to the server.

**What's working:** I get data from the boh server/database > webserver/client and data is displayed correctly when I hit the button data is packaged and send back to the boh server.
On the boh server i have a function that get the data array and parses it out, and sends an SMS message using twilio

**My issue:** I have to restart the server app to get it to process the data and send the message, if I hit the page button, it does all the stuff in the background it should, packages the array and sends the info to the server. The server is waiting for the data to be sent and client has sent the data, however it will only send off the text message is a stop and restart the node.js server, if i do that, the server starts and runs through the initial process of getting the sql data, and sets it up to be called when the app launches, then continues on to read that data was sent from the client, received and it will parse the data from the SMS message through a function send the message, wait a few seconds and then grab the response and confirm delivery of message. I am quite sure I am missing something basic here, but I have different functions but nothing I do will seem to get it to fire when the data is received.

I'm new at node and not very advanced in js, but I understand on some level why its not firing as is right, script is running, data has not been sent, so it stops when it gets here, then i hit the button, and it does nothing, because the script is stopped, and it doesn't has know way of knowing that data was sent, but when i rerun the script, the data that was sent is still sitting there wait to be received, so it recognizes the open websocket, and the sent data and work appropriately, I feel like a am missing something on the server side that tell it to wait for the data send but have not been able to make it work

```
twilws.onopen = async() => {//when the page button is presses, it starts a websocket server on the client, if that makes sense
        twilws.send('test')
        if (twilws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            logger.info('Twilio Sockpuppet Connected')
        } else {
            logger.error('Twilio Sockpuppet Fail')
        }

  twilws.onmessage = async (e) => {//after i hit the page button the server is on and the array is sent, i am trying to get this to be waiting for data and when it arrives go, but it will only do that when i restart the script
      
        try {
            data = JSON.parse(e.data);//parse the data
            logger.info('got the edata ' + e.data)
            //main(data) this will fire but not when the button is pressed.
        } catch (er) {
            logger.error('socket parse error: ' + e.data);
        }

    }
}


 twilws.onclose = () => {//close the connection, purges that data so that the websocket can be recreated and an array with new data sent.
        logger.info('Web Socket Connection Closed');
        twilws.close(1000, 'all done');
    };
```

**Here is the whole server**
I believe i may be blocking something, sorry about the bad formatting i have been changing and trying different things for a couple weeks off and on now and have not had a chance to clean thing up.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const db = require("./app/models");
const twilioconfig = require('./configs/twilioConfig.js');
const path = require('path');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const sql = require('mssql');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
const WebSocketFrame = require('websocket').frame;
/*const WebSocketRouter = require('websocket').router;*/
const W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const twilio = require('twilio');
const { Console } = require("console");
app.disable('view cache');
const pino = require('pino')
const SonicBoom = require('sonic-boom')
const logger = require('pino')()
const transport = pino.transport({
    target: 'pino/file',
    options: { destination: './logs/logs.txt', level: 'info', mkdir: true, append: true }
})
pino(transport)
/*const dbConfig2 = require("./app/config/db.config.js");*/
/*const config = require("./app/config/config.js");*/
const { client } = require("websocket");
const { err } = require("./node_modules/pino-std-serializers/index");
const { setInterval } = require("node:timers/promises");
app.use(pino)
//const webserver = app.listen(8080, function () {
//    console.log('Node WEb Server is running..');
//});

var params = {
    autoReconnect: false,                 //Enable/Disable reconnect when the server closes connection (boolean)
    autoReconnectInterval: 1000,         //Milliseconds to wait between reconnect attempts (number)
    autoReconnectMaxRetries: 600,        //Max number of reconnect attempts to allow (number)
    requestTimeout: 30000,               //Milliseconds to wait for a response before resending the request (number)
    requestRetryInterval: 5000,          //Milliseconds between request retry checks. This garbage collects the retry queue (number)
    requestRetryQueueMaxLength: 10     //Max queue length of retry queue before old messages start getting dropped (number)
}

var wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8081 })









sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err)
        logger.error(err);

    const sqlRequest = new sql.Request();
    const sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 5 guest_name,guest_phone_number,CONVERT(varchar,creation_time, 126) AS creation_time,CONVERT(varchar,last_modified_timestamp, 126) AS last_modified_timestamp,party_size from dbo.WaitList where status = '4' AND CAST(creation_time as date) = CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) ORDER BY creation_time ASC";
    logger.info("query passes preflight.....lets get data")


    sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(err)
        } else {
            logger.info("We do preliminary query now.")
        }
        //console.table(data.recordset);
        //logger.info('rows affected ' + data.rowsAffected);
        //console.log(data.recordset[0]);

        var array = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.rowsAffected; i++) {
            var a = data.recordset[i];
            array.push(a);

        }




        wss.on('connection', ws => {
            logger.info('Client connection established')
             ws.on('message', function () {
                sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(err)
                    }
                    //console.table(data.recordset);
                    //logger.info(data.rowsAffected);
                    //console.log(data.recordset[0]);

                    var array = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.rowsAffected; i++) {
                        var a = data.recordset[i];
                        array.push(a);

                    }

                })

                wss.clients
                    .forEach(client => {
                        logger.info('sending data')
                        client.send(JSON.stringify(array))
                       

                    })

            })

            
        })

    })






});

const twilws = new W3CWebSocket('ws://172.16.0.101:8082', params);




twilws.onopen = () => {//when the page button is presses, it starts a websocket server on the client, if that makes sense
    twilws.send('test')
    if (twilws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        logger.info('Twilio Sockpuppet Connected')
    } else {
        logger.error('Twilio Sockpuppet Fail')
    }


    twilws.onmessage = async (e) => {//after i hit the page button the server is on and the array is sent, i am trying to get this to be waiting for data and when it arrives go, but it will only do that when i restart the script

        try {
            data = JSON.parse(e.data);//parse the data
            logger.info('got the edata ' + e.data)

            //main(data) this will fire but not when the button is pressed.
        } catch (er) {
            logger.error('socket parse error: ');
        }

    }

}






 twilws.onclose = () => {//close the connection, purges that data so that the websocket can be recreated and an array with new data sent.
        logger.info('Web Socket Connection Closed');
        twilws.close(1000, 'all done');
    };
   




 //async function main(s) {
 //   /* these settings are loaded from configs/twilioConfig.js, go here to set the store account info and edit message body.*/
 //   const TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = twilioconfig.twilioOptions.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
 //   const TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = twilioconfig.twilioOptions.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
 //   const STORE_TWILIO_NUMBER = twilioconfig.twilioOptions.STORE_TWILIO_NUMBER;
 //    const TEXT_TWILIO_BODY = twilioconfig.twilioOptions.TEXT_TWILIO_BODY;

     
 //    var messarray = new Array([s])
     

    

 //    var num = JSON.stringify(messarray[0][0][0])
 //    var state = JSON.stringify(messarray[0][0][1])
 //    logger.info(num + ', ' + state)
    

 //    var readyin = state
 //    var custnum = num


     


 //   /*logger.info(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + ' ' + TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)*/

 //   var customer = new twilio(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);//these are our twilio account sid and token, set in twilioConfig, get from oneNote

 //   if (readyin == 0) {
 //       waitmsg = TEXT_TWILIO_BODY + "Your Table is Ready!";

 //   } else if (readyin == 15) {
 //       waitmsg = TEXT_TWILIO_BODY + "Your Table will be ready in about 15 minutes!";

 //   }

 //   logger.info(`Recieved Form data.....Twilio data read successfully....`);//log that we got the data from the gui form
 //   // send the message to the customer number through twilio, custnum from form, from is the store number, alson in twilioConfig
 //   customer.messages.create({
 //       to: custnum,
 //       from: STORE_TWILIO_NUMBER,
 //       body: waitmsg

 //   })
 //       .then(message => {
 //           var messageid = message.sid
 //           logger.info(messageid + ' Hey i found this, we might need it in a sec')

 //           const msid = JSON.stringify({ "MessageSid": messageid })
 //           const twilid = messageid

 //           setTimeout(getStatus, 5000);

 //           function getStatus() {
 //               customer.messages(messageid).fetch()
 //                   .then(call => {
 //                       const d = new Date(call.dateCreated).toLocaleString();
 //                       const messageStatus = call.status

 //                       var twil_response_array = [twilid, messageStatus, d]
 //                       logger.info(twil_response_array)
 //                       wss.on('connection', ws => {

 //                           ws.on('message', function () {

 //                           })
 //                           wss.clients
 //                               .forEach(client => {
 //                                   client.send(twil_response_array)
 //                               })
 //                       })


 //                   })






 //           }


 //       //})

    
app.listen(8180, function () {

    logger.info('Server is running..');
});

});
```

Comment: What library do you use for websockets?

Comment: I'm using ws for my websockets

Comment: Im not sure what was wrong with the ws websockets lib on send, and on message, but switching to socket.io solved my issue. I now io.emit to a socket.on and it works perfectly. It seems that event driven functions work better with sokcet.io rather that using ws.